# Grunt run try catch and run shell command on error

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I would like grunt to 'catch' a grunt error and run a shell command and try again.

Here's a specific use case.

after this error.

```
[4mRunning "connect:livereload" (connect) task[24m]
[31mFatal error: Port 9000 is already in use by another process.[39m]
[Finished in 13.4s with exit code 1]
```

I would like to run the following shell command

```
lsof -P | grep ':9000' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

to kill the 'in use port' before trying again

`grunt-exec` will allow me to execute shell commands but I haven't found a plugin (or other method) that will let me catch this error.

I welcome any ideas that use either grunt or shell to solve this problem.